# A mysterious stackoverflow error?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I was just doing a warm up, and I stumbled upon this:

http://codingbat.com/prob/p145416

**The difference between the three methods is how I add to the start parameter in the recursive calls.**

I initially solved it with the second function listed, however it gave me the notorious stackoverflow error. The first one does not give me a stackoverflow error. Is there something wrong with this site, or is there a difference 1 and 2 i.e. a subtle piece of the Java language?

```
public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
    if (start >= nums.length) 
        return (target == 0);

    return groupSum(start+1, nums, target - nums[start]) || groupSum(start+1,      
       nums, target);
}
```

------------ These cause stack over flow errors --------------

```
public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
    if (start >= nums.length) 
        return (target == 0);

    return groupSum(start++, nums, target - nums[start]) || groupSum(start++,      
       nums, target);
}

public boolean groupSum(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
    if (start >= nums.length) 
        return (target == 0);

    return groupSum(++start, nums, target - nums[start]) || groupSum(++start,      
       nums, target);
}
```

Comment: There's nothing mysterious a stackoverflow error, it just means that your recursive method never stopped. Why? Probably for a wrong design of the base case. Also, please don't say this only happens *in Java*, it could happen on other programming languages as well.

Comment: Also I realize how inane these functions are since they have a complexity of O(2^n). I am doing a warm up for an interview and need practice with recursion.

Comment: All three functions have the same base case. They only differ in how I add to start. I will clarify the question.

Comment: Something to do with postincrement operator getting evaluated after the statement is completed?

Comment: Hey, you can delete it yourself..

Answer (score 4):

This is a notoriously subtle bug.  Take a look at this recursive call:

```
groupSum(start++, nums, target - nums[start])
```

Notice that you are passing `start++` as the first parameter.  This uses the postfix `++` operator, which does the following:

- Increment `start`, then
- Return the value that `start` used to have.

In other words, this will update the *local* copy of `start` to be `start + 1`, then pass the old value of `start` into the recursive call.  This means that `start` never changes from call to call, so the base case never triggers, hence the stack overflow.  You can confirm this by putting a `System.out.println` statement at the top of your function.

There may be other issues here, but I suspect this is your culprit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't explain why it fails on ++start :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Not true. ++start returns start+1 so it should not recurse infinitely.

Comment: @Patashu you're right. Now evaluating the cause of `++start` giving a SOE.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza It won't and it can't, try it yourself.

Comment: @Patashu its supposed to not throw SOE (no need to try it in code btw). The problem is of other kind: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, and this really seems ok because you use `++start` and the you evaluate `nums[start]` just after `start` has increased its value on 1. I'm just very tired (1 a.m. here) and not thinking clearly.

Comment: @LLL I'm not tired enough to just copy/paste your proposed solutions in the link you posted and then **read** the error descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

`++start` (known as pre-increment) evaluates to `start+1`. `start++` (known as post-increment, as in the increment is done AFTER evaluation) evaluates to `start`. Both of them set the value in the variable to `start+1` as a side-effect of evaluation. So, when you do `start++` you pass `start` to the next call of the method, which passes `start` to the next call of the method... you never reach the base case and you recurse infinitely.

Comment: Using ++start also causes a stackoverflow. I thought the same thing initially. It may just be a bug on the site.

Comment: @LLL I don't believe it. (I also don't believe it could be a bug on the site. It would be using the same compiler as you.)

Comment: I gave you the link to the site ;) I am really good at finding bugs. It is a curse.

Comment: @LLL In my experience 'being really good at finding bugs' means 'really good at accidentally typing something other than what they came up with in their head and not realizing what happened'. Unless you're working with someone else's buggy code, expect compilers to work, well tested widely used libraries to just work, etc.

Comment: I agree with some of what you said, and that's why I am on here. This is a bit perplexing. The creator of the site could be using an old version of Java.

Comment: @LL Using an old version of Java would not do it. The semantics of pre-increment have not changed.

Comment: True, and the language is quite old. ++ is a very basic piece of syntax.

Comment: @LLL Please see Luiggi Mendoza's latest comment on the other answer